# Order by not works in android simulator

Tags: android, sql, sql-order-by, emulation, simulator

I have this code but order by not works on android simulator.

What do I have to do to fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1=@Parameter1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: What do you mean by **not working** ?

Comment: it works like I used order by asc